# Merge two 7zip archive into one archive

Tags: windows, compression, 7-zip

The usual approach to merge two archives to unpack both archives and repackage.

Is there a way to merge two or multiple 7zip archives into one archive?

Comment: One way is to simply create a new archive containing the two separate Zip files.

Answer (score 1):

7-zip File Manager has 2-panel mode. To merge contents of one archive into another, open both archives in the two panels, select all files in the archive-to-merge, and drag them over to the archive-to-be-merged-into. 7-zip will then add those files to the second archive.

Since that is possible in the file manager, I believe you can do that from command line as well, but I did not research that.